# Preview JPEGs in folder in Dolphin

Tags: filemanager, dolphin, jpeg

I'm running Kubuntu 22.04.   When I open a folder of JPEGs on my camera in Dolphin, I want the icons to be the images in those JPEGs. I go to Configure/General/Preview and I make sure that JPEG Images is checked. I then have two queries:

```
Skip previews for local files above
Skip previews for remote files above
```

I don't know if the JPEG files are considered remote or local (the camera is connected to the computer by a USB cable). But in any case, I can't find answers to these queries that will cause the JPEG images to be used as the icons in the listing of files. The choice for local files is either **No limit** or a size; the choice for remote files is either **No previews** or a size.

Comment: I believe this may be a consequence of the limitations of the MTP protocol, which is probably how your camera is connected to your computer. I recall that MTP does not allow for actually viewing the contents of files until they have been transferred to your PC. If I can find an authoritative source, I'll post an answer (or perhaps someone else knows). In any case, this is a lead.

Comment: If I open the camera in Gwenview rather than Dolphin, I can preview the JPEG files immediately.